# Haskell - unmodified variable in a recursive function

Tags: haskell, recursion

I have a list of char and integer like `[('1',1),('2',2),('3',3),('4',4),('5',5)]` and want to turn the integers into the percentage each number count for the total such as `[('1',7),('2',13),('3',20),('4',27),('5',33)]`. I have tried a recursive function which takes a parameter as `(c,i):rest` and then divide the `i` by the total and then call the function with `rest`. But after every single loop, the total has changed. So is there any way I declare the total from start and use it over and over like other languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to calculate the total in advance - you can use something like

```
f :: Integral b => [(a,b)] -> [(a,b)]
f lst = let total = sum $ map snd list
         in map (\(x,y) -> (x,(100 * y)`div` total)) lst
```

Note: it would be a good idea to collect the `Integral`-values associated to each character beforehand, this makes the output a bit more clear (in my opinion), but this would be an exercise for the astute reader.

To make this function more clear - I would also recommend introducing `newtypes` for `Value` and `Percentage` such that you never try to add values with percentages.

```
newtype Value a = V {extractV :: a}
newtype Percentage = P {percent :: Integer}

f :: Integral b => [(a,Value b)] -> [(a,Percentage)]
```

Comment: Minor nitpick: you don't absolutely need to calculate the total *in advance* - you can compute the list result and the total in a single traversal of the input list, all thanks to the magic of laziness.

Comment: @user2407038 I don't fully understand that - how can you use the sum-total  without it being previously calculated and run this in a single traversal. do you mean that the computation of the percentage is deferred until the list is fully evaluated?